# alfred script that "waits until key pressed..."

Tags: bash, suspend, alfred

I try to write a /bin/bash Script in [alfred](https://www.alfredforum.com/) and that Script shall pause at one point - and continue when the user presses a keyboard-key (or other shortcut).

I tried the following bash-cmd (see below) that starts a process and then on the second line tries to suspend the same process. But, unfortunately, the script simply continues without suspending !

```
/usr/local/bin/myProcessName $arg0

pkill -STOP -nf '/?(bash|sh)[ ]+(.*/)?'"myProcessName"'( |$)'

/usr/local/bin/myProcessName $arg1
```

The idea here was to give alfred another shortcut script that resumes the same process again, such as:

```
pkill -CONT -nf '/?(bash|sh)[ ]+(.*/)?'"myProcessName"'( |$)'
```

But again, the suspending did not work in the first place !

I also tried to give the full path to the process-name such as :
(but no difference - there is no pause in the script !)

```
/usr/local/bin/myProcessName $arg0

pkill -STOP -nf '/?(bash|sh)[ ]+(.*/)?'"/usr/local/bin/myProcessName"'( |$)'

/usr/local/bin/myProcessName $arg1
```

How else can I give alfred the functionality I need (i..e calling an app with one argument, then let the user decide when the second argument shall be processed (i.e. by "press key to continue..." funtionality ???)

Comment: How long does `myProcessName` take to run? If it is quick, then it will already have exited before the `pkill` can stop it. Have you thought about having `myProcessName` suspend itself when it starts? That's just `kill -STOP $$` isn't it? That said, if you want to pass in a second argument, would you be better off using a named pipe or something like that?

Comment: Hi Jon - thank you for your ideas! The `myProcessName` definitively takes longer and it has not excited before the `pkill` (I verified that). I don't follow your idea completely yet (about making `myProcessName`suspend itself when it starts. How would I resume it from the outside ? About the `named pipe`: I will look into that....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but if you are trying to pass in two parameters, one after a delay, how about using named pipes?

If you create a named pipe

```
mknod /tmp/foo.pipe p
```

and use a script like this, call it `stop.sh`,

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1=$1
arg2=$(cat <foo.pipe)

echo $arg1 $arg2
```

you could run

```
bash stop.sh foo
```

then write the second parameter to the pipe from another shell or process

```
echo bar >>/tmp/foo.pipe
```

Until the second parameter is written to the pipe, the script will be blocked.

Comment: good idea - only question: can the user decide (with keyboard-shortcut) when the de-blocking shall happen ? And if yes, how ?

Comment: If you can arrange for the keyboard shortcut to write something to the pipe, then yes you can.

Comment: Jon, I finally achieved a solution with a combination between Swift scripting and alfred scripting. The decision not to take your solution was mainly since I have an arbitrary amount of arg's. And therefore I create several alfred scripts - each calling the swift-script with its own argument. A bit of a trade-off but it works. Again, thanks for you help.